# Why am I not receiving this PG notification?

Tags: postgresql

I've opened two database consoles, using `rails dbconsole`. I issued the following command in both of them:

```
listen ninja;
```

And, in the second console, I also wrote:

```
notify ninja;
```

However, only the second console sees this notification:

```
NOTIFY
Asynchronous notification "ninja" received from server process with PID 16837.
```

Why aren't both consoles receiving the notification? Is there some setting that I can do to have both of them receive it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about rails dbconsole, but with psql the program doesn't show notifications until the next time you execute a command, because notifications are pulled, not pushed, and the console doesn't constantly poll for them while inactive.  I assume dbconsole is similar.

Comment: That seems to be the case. This question also mentions something similar, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144244/cant-immediately-receive-multiple-notifications-in-npgsql?rq=1 .